# User Profile Synchronization - not stopping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service, central-administration

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? Our User Profile Stopped working about two weeks ago therefore none of our AD content is being updated across to our SP site which we rely on for searching user information. We have lost our connection and it is now just hung up when you go to create a new instance. I receive the same error when I attempt to Create a new connection.

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop `user profile synchronization service` via PowerShell and restart it again as the following:

- Open SharePoint Management Shell via Administrator.
- Type `Get-SPServiceInstance`
- Right click inside the PowerShell window and select “Mark” the corresponding ID for the `user profile synchronization service`. hit enter to copy it.
- Now Type `Stop-SPServiceInstance -identity` > Right click inside the PowerShell Shell and select “paste”.
- Your cmdlet should be look something like this:

> Stop-SPServiceInstance -identity d8c3a67b-0917-4aeb-9053-a310a40154d6

- Again run Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity  to be like this

> Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity
>   d8c3a67b-0917-4aeb-9053-a310a40154d6

- Now try to create a new connection.

For more details check [Stopping SharePoint Service Application using PowerShell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/30/stopping-sharepoint-2010-service-applications-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas - I have given something similar a go without success but I will do this again to see if I come up with a better outcome. I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas. The service finally stopped by itself and was able to be restarted. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you!

Comment: I can't be sure if it was this method as I had tried it twice before or the system stopped of its own accord. Thanks for you help.

Comment: NP, you are welcome :)